# Precision and recall for outlier detection

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am trying to calculate precision, recall and f1-score for outlier detection (in my case attacks in a network) using a one-class SVM. I encounter a problem in doing that in a rigorous manner. I explain myself. Since precision is calculated like:

precision = true_positive /(true_positive + false_positive)

if I do my tests using a dataset that I already know that has a few number of attacks then the number of false_positive will be really big in comparison with the true_positive, therefore precision will be very low. 
However, if I use a dataset that I already know that has lots of attacks, without changing my detection algorithm the number of true_positive will increase and then the precision will be higher.

I know that something must be wrong in the way that I calculate precision. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> if I do my tests using a dataset that I already know that has a few number of attacks then the number of false_positive will be really big in comparison with the true_positive, therefore precision will be very low.

That is (probably) expected behavior, because your data set is skewed. However, you should get a [recall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) value that is acceptable.

> However, if I use a dataset that I already know that has lots of attacks, without changing my detection algorithm the number of true_positive will increase and then the precision will be higher.

And in this case, I bet recall will be low.

Based on what you describe, there are a few issues and things you can do. I can address more specific issues if you add more information to your question:

1. Why are you using multiple test sets, all of which are unbalanced? You should use something that is balanced, or even better, use [k-fold cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) with your entire data set. Use it to find the best parameters for your model.
2. To decide if you have a good enough balance between precision and recall, consider using the [F1 score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score).
3. Use a [confusion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) to decide if your measures are acceptable.
4. Plot [learning curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_curve) to help avoid overfitting.